# Is there a slowest growing uncomputable function?

Tags: computability

The question [Is busy beaver the fastest growing function known to man?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4678/is-busy-beaver-the-fastest-growing-function-known-to-man) is answered negatively, pointing out that arbitrarily fast growing functions can be constructed.

But is there a "reachable" *lower* bound for uncomputable functions, or can the growth rate be just e.g. endlessly halved while still remaining uncomputable?

Comment: Undecidable decision problems (e.g. the halting problem) can be represented as functions that return a single bit. That's $O(1)$, which is quite slow-growing.

Comment: Are you two taking the same class, by any chance?

Comment: Nope, I just came across the busy beaver question and wondered